# DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a variable [ err ]

Tags: java, int

I searched here a bit to find an answer but the answers I found didn't helped me alot so I created a new post..

The error is here:

```
private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

private int[] pixels =((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

// error

```
DataBufferInt cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Any help?

Comment: Java.
the * that because I added italic :/

Answer (score 4):

Please import `DataBufferInt` :

```
 import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
```